# Send emails from the user that is logged in in my GAE application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail

Let's assume I have users registered in my GAE application with their Google accounts that they use to access GMail, Calendar, Contacts etc. They confirm that my app can send email messages from their GMail account and when they click some link, like "Send a notification to all my friends", the message goes where it's supposed to go from the users' GMail accounts. Is that possible to do without asking users to share their login and password with my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GAE [Mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) docs:

> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address must be one of the following types:
>
> - The address of a registered
>     administrator for the application.
>     You can add administrators to an
>     application using the Administration
>     Console.
> - **The address of the user for
>     the current request signed in with a
>     Google Account**. You can determine the
>     current user's email address with the
>     Users API.
> - Any valid email receiving
>     address for the app (such as
>     xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).

So, if they are logging into your app using the Users API, you can just set the `sender`  to the email address associated with the user's account:

```
message.sender = users.get_current_user().email()
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need to get user confirmation to send email 'from' the user.  All they need to do is log in.  Though, you're likely to get your app suspended if you misbehave with users' email addresses.

Comment: is via OAuth possible. Can I sign them in using an OAuth token and send the email.